# Bake Textures after adding nodes

Tags: uv, shaders, texture-baking, baking

World,

i am fairly new to Blender, so please treat me as a noob.
I have the following scenario: I exported a Model from Google Maps, duplicated the model, created a UV Map of the new model, decimated the vertices, created one single material and backed the original texture on the duplicated model:
[image]

Afterwards, I added the Color correction nodes shown above.

[image]

My Problem is the following: how do I re-bake this new version of texture onto the model?
Or better: how do I extract the texture.png with the color corrected textures?

Is there a way or should I correct the color before I bake the original texture?

I would be happy about any help!

Comment: I don't get the point: if you've successfully baked once, why can't you bake again? Anyway to do it, just create a new image texture, save it put it as unconnected node in the shader and select this node. Now go to the bake panel.

Comment: This was my first idea. But when i try to bake, i get the message "No valid selected objects" [link](https://pasteboard.co/JoKAuwG.png)

Comment: 'selected to active' is still checked

Comment: Sadly, the result does not change [link](https://pasteboard.co/JoKC3ZL.png)

Comment: well, is the object to bake selected?

Comment: Ok, I see my mistake. It seems to be working right now! Thank you kindly sir.